# Android ENOENT with some files

Tags: java, android, file, enoent

I use a Intent to get pictures path and open them into a File. I can open files allocated in "Camera" folder like "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160817_232858.jpg", but I cannot open files in locations like "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1634894_.png". Using file.exists() it just says that it doesn't.
Need to say that I'm using API 23 and I request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, so this souldn`t be a problem... But I can't access those files even with that.
What can be wrong?

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            File file = new File(picturePath);
            if(file.exists()) {

            } else {

            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Updated: it doesn't happens with all the files from the same folder, just some of them, but they really exist since I can open them from the gallery.

Update2:
I use this Intent.

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

Update3:
Running time permissions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SomeWork();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
            }
            else { 
                SomeWork();
            }
```

Permissions in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: are you running on 6.0?

Comment: Yes, I use Marshmallow

Comment: have you get runtime permissions?

Comment: Yes, I do, I request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE before executing the Intent.

Comment: Why not just use the `Uri` directly? Beyond that, what is the **exact** `Intent` that you are using?

Comment: Becase even if I use Uri, it keeps happening. Updated with the Intent @CommonsWare

Comment: add your permissions code how you are getting them.

Comment: "Becase even if I use Uri, it keeps happening" -- because **what** keeps happening? When you use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, what happens?

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean "!file.exists()", that happens. PD: Updated Sohail

Comment: @PaulD have you override `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaStore` will index images that are not accessible to you from the filesystem. There is no requirement for a `DATA` column to return a value that you can use.

Instead, stop trying to get a `File`, and [use the `Uri` itself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html):

- `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on it
- `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` for easy access to metadata (e.g., MIME type)

Comment: Still cannot access the same files.

Comment: Here you have: https://i.gyazo.com/0bf31c2030baf9f0a4e36ba71777c028.png But the other files works fine

Comment: @PaulD: OK, now that's rather bizarre. Just to confirm: your code there is directly triggered by `onActivityResult()` (much like the code in your question), using the `Uri` that you got in the result `Intent`? It's not some saved `Uri` from some past run of your app, right? Because if that were the case, your problem is that [your rights to access content identified by a `Uri` is very time-limited](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: I just did that to try. 1-Yes, 2-Yes, 3-Yes. I think not, I do all the work in the same activity and I can open the rest of the files, just some of them are not accessible.

Comment: @PaulD: I can't explain this. Is there anything unusual about the images that you cannot access (e.g., they are on removable storage)? What device(s) are you testing on that give you this behavior?

Comment: They are in default "Picture" folder and are visible from the Gallery. I'm testing in bq Aquaris M5.5.

Comment: @PaulD: Well, any pre-installed gallery-style app might have enhanced rights. You might try installing some other gallery-style app and see if it can see those images.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
 // this works!!!
 File csvfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/brcOrdersaved.csv");
        final String filename = csvfile.toString();

        if (!csvfile.exists()) {
            // displayMsg(context, "No Saved Order: ");
            return (false);
        } 
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String csvLine = "";
        final char Separator = ',';
        final char Delimiter = '"';
        final char LF = '\n';
        final char CR = '\r';
        boolean quote_open = false;
        if (reader.equals(null)) {
            displayMsg(context, "NULL");
            return (false);//rww 11/13/2021
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (!myendofcsvfile) {

            csvLine = reader.readLine();
            if (csvLine == null) {
                myendofcsvfile = true;

            } 
                // do stuff here
        }

        fr.close();
        fileexists = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        String msg = "Can not Load Saved Order ";
        fileexists = false;
        return (fileexists);

    }
```